# Cannot change tomcat configs in AWS through .ebextensions files

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, java-opts

I am trying to increase Java heap size in tomcat in a Beanstalk application. For that, I created a YAML config file (named `tomcat.config`) as follows:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions
    option_name: Xms
    value: 256m
    option_name: Xmx
    value: 1024m
    option_name: XX:MaxPermSize
    value: 64m
```

I have placed this file within `src/main/resources/.ebextensions/` directory.

When I deploy this war on tomcat, I don't see `Xmx2014m` in tomcat. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can configure the JVM heap size (min and max) on the configuration tab of the elastic beanstalk console. Not exactly an answer to your question, but it could help you get where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks @Theyna. I got it to work after some trials. I guess I hadn't created the YAML properly.

Comment: always good to know you got something to work +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me, in case anyone else needs the answer.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions
    option_name: Xmx
    value: 1024m
```

Comment: The above config resides in `my-project-dir/src/main/resources/.ebextensions/tomcat.config`.

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS Elastic Beanstalk documentation for [Tomcat platform configuration](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-elastic-beanstalk-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/java-tomcat-platform.md#tomcat-configuration-namespaces), it can be done in this way:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions:
    Xms: 256m
    Xmx: 1024m
```

But in case you ever made any manual changes to those options in EB web console, those settings will always take precedence and corresponding option settings in extension config file will be ignored.

See this discussion:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=403076&#403076